# Blurry text and graphics, and $failed everywhere

Tags: linux, user-interface

I am using Manjaro GNOME 21.1.5, and I was able to install Mathematica no problem. However, the interface looks glitched out with blurry text and graphics, and many of the usual buttons' text replaced with '$Failed' (see attached pictures).

I tried contacting Wolfram support, but they just told me that Manjaro is not one of their supported operating systems, which wasn't very helpful. I tried using Manjaro KDE 21.1.5, and everything worked perfectly, but I want it to work on GNOME because I don't like KDE. I tried doing a "Manual Clean Start" as one user recommended on another question of a similar nature. Nothing worked, and I still have this problem.

Mathematica is usable, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the actual function of the program, but the user interface is extremely annoying to use. I know Manjaro and GNOME are both pretty popular, so I'm hoping someone here has managed to solve this issue.

[image: $Failed]

[image: more $Failed]

[image: blurry suggestions text]

[image: blurry splash screen]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no idea about the $Failed, although it seems pretty likely it's missing a basic resource somewhere. I'm surprised everything else is working. As for the blurriness, that's been an issue for a while particularly on hi-res displays. It's sorted out now in Windows, but I haven't used Mathematica on Linux in years, so it's possible that's lagging behind. If so, my workaround in the past involved futzing with the global magnification level and default font size. Not ideal, but it helped.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689975/failed-in-the-mathematica-interface/67409751#67409751) with an answer describing a partial solution. Changing the "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode" option to "True" gets rid of all the $Failed. But after the change, the UI looks even worse (it is huge as well as blurry)

Comment: The blurriness scales along with the text when you change font size and/or change magnification level to 1.5 or 2x? If not, then see if you can find settings you can live with; if so, then this is a different problem and you'll have to wait for someone smarter than me to come along.

Comment: The blurriness does not scale along with the text. In fact, the blurry UI elements don't seem to scale along with the text at all (I added some new screenshots to the original question for demonstration).

Comment: Using Mathematica on Gnome 40 on Pop!_OS, I don't have this issue. I do know that KDE and Gnome use different approaches for High-DPI scaling and displays, and I also believe Pop!_OS has a [high-dpi daemon](https://github.com/pop-os/hidpi-daemon) which may be emulating KDE's method, or somehow alleviating the problem. Perhaps looking in that direction may produce some answers.